# How to count views for each post by using php script?

Tags: php, view, count

I'm going to create a dynamic website, I want display multiple posts at a page & need to count view for each post Separately.
Can you help me?

Comment: Please show us what you've already done. Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way:

1. Create a views column on your posts table (database)
2. After have page view increase view then update again to posts table

Btw, you should write code and show. At least, you should show the database

Comment: Please any example